# Thread.sleep не работает в ActionListner

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing, jframe, try-catch

Ищу решение проблемы в сети - не могу найти. Хочу сделать, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку `ProgressBar` заполнялся от 1 до 100, но почему-то он не показывает, что заполняется ежесекундно, а, только когда полностью пройдет 100 секунд, показывает его заполнение.

Причем если делать это не в ActionListner то все работает...

```
public class Frame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = getFrame();

        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton();

        frame.add(panel);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(progressBar);

        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setMinimum(0);
        progressBar.setMaximum(100);

        progressBar.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    progressBar.setValue(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    static JFrame getFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame() { };

        frame.setSize(600, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проснулся с утра, и на свежую голову вроде как пришло решение, наткнулся на класс `Timer`, начал читать и увидел что там можно планировать задачи, в общем, изменил  код.

Я далеко не прогер, а так после работы в свободное время по-немногу учусь делать всякую ерунду, просто интересно)).

Таймер, я так понимаю, у меня работает без остановки, как его остановить  теперь, вопрос?

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setValue(progressBar.getValue() + 1);
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer("Timer");
        long delay = 1000;
        timer.schedule(timerTask, delay, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

потому что обычный `Thread.sleep` вводит в сон **ВСЁ** активити.
для решения этой проблемы попробуйте использовать поток:

```
Thread s1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // code 
    }
});
s1.start();
```

В вашем случае это (может где-то ошибка. я не проверял ваш пример):

```
Thread s1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            progressBar.setValue(i);
        }
    }
});
s1.start();
```

Вы вешаете этот код на кнопку `Listener`. Запускается отдельный поток, который сам себе что-то считает, ждет, изменяет независимо от всего остального.

p.s. Еще одним решением может быть знакомство с `ExecutorService`.
вот отличная ссылка: https://habr.com/ru/post/116363/

Comment: Спасибо , тоже посмотрю